# Show org-mode hyperlink as plain text

Tags: org-mode

Although it is convenient how org-mode shows hyperlinks, there are times when I want to see the underlying plain text, e.g. `[[./file.org][Title]]`. How can I do this?

I know about `org-insert-link`, but it is not what I want:

> C-c C-l runs the command org-insert-link, which is an interactive compiled Lisp
>   function in `org.el'.
>
> ...
>
> If there is already a link at point, this command will allow you to edit link
>   and description parts.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I just found a nice function in the org source code: `M-x org-toggle-link-display`.

Here is the source code, just for fun:

```
(defun org-toggle-link-display ()
  "Toggle the literal or descriptive display of links."
  (interactive)
  (if org-descriptive-links
      (progn (org-remove-from-invisibility-spec '(org-link))
         (org-restart-font-lock)
         (setq org-descriptive-links nil))
    (progn (add-to-invisibility-spec '(org-link))
       (org-restart-font-lock)
       (setq org-descriptive-links t))))
```

Comment: This. Also, if you want to keep this behavior permanently, simply add `(setq org-descriptive-links nil)` to your init file.

Comment: Note this variable is accessible from the "Org > Hyperlinks" menu

Comment: Thanks - I just bound C-u C-c C-l to this. Very handy.  `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-u C-c C-l") 'org-toggle-link-display)`

Answer (score 21):

A useful way to do this is

```
M-x font-lock-mode
```

which toggles font locking.  When font locking is off, the hyperlink is visible in its undecorated form `[[./file.org][Title]]`.  This can be a useful approach for seeing other pieces of mark-up in the buffer.

Comment: thanks! extended [below](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/63516/5444)

Answer (score 3):

I've been using this function. It will toggle between
`fundamental-mode` and the original mode (`org-mode` in this case).
It's a bit weird, but I like it:

```
(defun illiterate ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((coding-system-for-read 'utf-8))
    (if (eq major-mode 'fundamental-mode)
        (revert-buffer nil t)
      (let ((pt (1+ (length
                     (encode-coding-string
                      (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point))
                      'utf-8))))
            (file-name (buffer-file-name)))
        (kill-buffer (current-buffer))
        (find-file-literally file-name)
        (goto-char pt)))))
```

Comment: Why can't you just call fundamental-mode?

Comment: Plain `fundamental-mode` won't work, since `org-mode` messes too much
with text properties and they don't get reset. It needs to be the way it is.

Answer (score 2):

A low-tech way is to move point to the beginning of the link text and type C-d (i.e., invoke `org-delete-char`).  That removes the first "[" character, so that you no longer have a properly formatted hyperlink, and you can see the remainder of it as raw text.  Then when you're done, just invoke `undo` to restore it to what you had previously.

Comment: This did not work for me in Emacs 24.4 (9.0) on Mac OS X with the default org installation.

Comment: (This is a comment to user98761's answer. Since I am not allowed to comment, I'll just write an answer here.) I like user98761's answer. Simple and straightforward. However, C-d does not work on the evil-mode EMACS on MY Mac, while the evil command 'x' works like a charm. More explicitly, move point to the beginning of the link text and type 'x'.

Comment: I'm no evil-mode expert. But surely 'x' as a Vi command does the same thing as C-d in regular Emacs. So it's really equivalent, I suspect.

Answer (score 2):

Org mode achieves the link effect using the following code:

```
(if org-descriptive-links (add-to-invisibility-spec '(org-link)))
```

This adds `org-link` to the variable `buffer-invisibility-spec` which means that text which has its invisible property set to `org-link` will be hidden.

Using `M-x visible-mode RET` you can reset `buffer-invisibility-spec` temporary to `nil`, which means the hidden text will be shown from there on.

Using `M-x visible-mode RET` again you can reset `buffer-invisibility-spec` to its previous value, which will hide the relevant text parts again.

Comment: @Drew Better now? I don't know what else do add

Comment: @Drew Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

(Extending Andrew Swann [above](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5417/5444)) Following may be a superset of what you want, but here goes:

I typically want to see all the markup (for everything, not just for links), occasionally switching back to the default/pretty display (mostly as a form of Org syntax validation). Hence I mostly set my display to

1. turn off font-lock mode in my Org buffers, with effects as described by Swann above.
2. *wrap* aka [*continue* my lines](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Continuation-Lines.html#Continuation-Lines) (which in Emacsish is the opposite of [*truncating* lines](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Line-Truncation.html)) to show all of each line.

But I am also still an Org noob, so I put the following comment at the top (TOF) of most of my Org files, ensuring that the 1st line in the comment is the 1st line of the file (thus becoming a [local file variables list](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html))

```
# -*- truncate-lines: nil; eval: (font-lock-mode -1); -*-
# 1. unset->wrap long lines in display, set->don't show continuation lines
# 2. unset->show undecorated text (e.g., don't prettify hyperlinks), set->display pretty
```

Eventually I'll either put this in my [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html), or just adapt to the default Way of Org. But for now, it both

1. configures the display behavior I want by default.
2. reminds me what to do to get back to the default Org display. I don't yet want to put this in my init.el, because that makes it harder for me to remember how to toggle these display aspects.

Note also that

1. `truncate-lines` is a normal variable, so one can just set it=`nil` as above. But ...
2. `font-lock-mode` is a [minor mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minor-Modes.html), so that requires the `eval` above to turn off, per [The Fine Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html)).
3. You can also put the local-variables list at EOF with different syntax ([RTFM again](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html)), but I'm more likely to see it at TOF.